# Deploying tomcat/mysql application on windows

Tags: windows, mysql, tomcat, java

Our web service software consists of a (precompiled) war file and a mysql database. We provide installation packages to deploy it on Ubuntu or Fedora, in a standard Tomcat7/MySQL/Apache2 setup using `mod_proxy_ajp`.

Now some people have asked if they can try our software on windows. It should be possible, but I have no experience with deploying on an OS without a package manager. Is there a way to provide a self contained installer for windows that will include Java, Tomcat7 and MySQL? Something like wamp but then with tomcat and java instead of php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create your own MSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx) and silently install all of the necessary components, assuming their individual installers support it.

Or you can use something like [IExpress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress) to make a self-extracting executable that contains all of the binaries and kicks off an install script.

Comment: Mmm i'll give this a try. Doubt it will work for Java though.

Comment: Why not? Java can be silently installed. How do you think large enterprise customers deploy it en masse to their users? In fact, I've deployed at least two dozen versions of Java to ~1000 lab computers over the years when I worked at a university.

Comment: That sounds very promising. Will MSI automatically resolve conflicts if the user already has Java installed?

Comment: You can use whatever logic you want in the installer. It's not a magical one-click and you have a custom installer type thing. You need to code or script the logic in. You can make it do whatever you want. Think of it like a .deb or .rpm sort of.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to forget that you can also just write a one click batch file that lives in a self-executable *.zip or *.rar.  The file unzips, executes whatever 'silent' install options (i.e. for mysql and java) and your own software installation.

http://www.win-rar.com/download.html?&L=0

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I've already said in the second half of my answer? IExpress (a native windows packaging tool) can create a one-click self-extracting executable that can then kick off a batch script if desired.

Comment: Sure, it's a very similar approach; IExpress would result in a much more professional looking package, but could also be a bit more intimidating for someone unfamiliar with windows packaging tools, imo.  I only added that windows also has command line batch files, and suggested a couple of basic packaging tools.